# Как подключить стиль css в php файле?

Tags: php, html, css

Как подключить стиль `css` в `php` файле?
 В `header` подключила, а в другой файл - не получается.
Есть файл `header.php`, в котором подключается `css`, это работает ок.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type = "text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

А есть файл `file1.php`, в котором `include header.php`:

```
<?php 
include("header.php");
 ?>
```

В файле `file1.php` вызывается css стиль:

```
<ul class="first">
  <li>Строка 1</li>
</ul>
```

Но на сайте он не отображается. Что нужно добавить в код?

---

У меня все файлы в одной папке пока, для простоты.

Comment: Можете показать html который генерирует php скрипт file1.php

Comment: проверьте пути к файлам

Comment: <?php 
include("header.php");
 ?>
 

 
 <ul class="first">
  <li>Тестовый текст</li>
</ul>

<?php 
include("footer.php");
 ?>

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы указываете путь к стилю относительно `header.php`, а вам нужно указать путь относительно `file1.php`.

Comment: я их для простоты пока разместила в одной папке )) там в названии файла путей нет.

Comment: А вы локальный сервер запустили?

Comment: Да, я загружаю файлы на хостинг и потом проверяю сайт.

Comment: Если у вас до сих пор эта проблема, добавьте больше информации, например скрин архитектуры.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "&lt;link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\">"
```